# How to remove an apparent singularity in NDSolve?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, warning-messages, singularity, version-13.2

I'm trying to numerically solve two coupled differential equations using NDSolve.  The following code works, except that I had to remove a starting point singularity at $r = 0$ by adding an arbitrary 0.01 value in a function (see the comment, in the code):

```
Clear["Global`*"] 

rmax = 1;

rho[p_, gamma_] := p^(1/gamma) + p/(gamma - 1)
TOV[p_, m_, r_, gamma_] := - (m + 4 Pi p r^3) (rho[p, gamma] + p)/((r + 0.01) (r + 0.01 - 2 m)) (* Notice the 0.01 to remove a singularity *)

solution[q_, gamma_] := NDSolve[{
    p'[r] == TOV[p[r], m[r], r, gamma], (* Equ. 1 *)
    m'[r] == 4 Pi rho[p[r], gamma] r^2, (* Equ. 2 *)
    p[0] == q, (* Central pressure *)
    m[0] == 0, (* Mass at center *)
    WhenEvent[(p[r] < 0 || 2 m[r] >= r), "StopIntegration"]
    }, {p, m}, {r, 0, rmax},
    Method -> "StiffnessSwitching",
    MaxSteps -> Automatic
]

pressure[q_, gamma_] := Plot[Evaluate[p[r] /. solution[q, gamma]], {r, 0, rmax}, PlotRange -> All]

Manipulate[Show[pressure[q, gamma], PlotRange -> {{0, rmax}, {0, q}}],
    {{q, 0.5, Style["Central pressure", Italic, 10]}, 0, 1, 0.01},
    {{gamma, 4/3, Style["gamma", Italic, 10]}, 1.01, 5/3 - 0.01, 0.01}
]
```

Preview of what this code is doing:

[image]

Yet, there should be a way to integrate both equations from $r = 0$ and up (without adding a pesky 0.01 value), since there's a finite limit at that starting point (i.e since $m(0) = 0$).  So how should I tell Mathematica to evaluate that limit, without adding the 0.01 arbitrary value?

**EDIT:**  Micheal's trick of the PieceWise function works for the code above, but NOT for the simpler version below (classical non-relativistic version):

```
Clear["Global`*"] 

rmax = 1;

rho[p_, gamma_] := p^(1/gamma)
classical[p_, m_, r_, gamma_] := - m rho[p, gamma]/r^2

solution[q_, gamma_] := NDSolve[{
    p'[r] == PieceWise[{{0, r <= 0}, {classical[p[r], m[r], r, gamma], r > 0}}], (* Equ. 1 *)
    m'[r] == 4 Pi rho[p[r], gamma] r^2, (* Equ. 2 *)
    p[0] == q, (* Central pressure *)
    m[0] == 0, (* Mass at center *)
    WhenEvent[(p[r] < 0 || 2 m[r] >= r), "StopIntegration"]
    }, {p, m}, {r, 0, rmax},
    Method -> "StiffnessSwitching",
    MaxSteps -> Automatic
]

pressure[q_, gamma_] := Plot[Evaluate[p[r] /. solution[q, gamma]], {r, 0, rmax}, PlotRange -> All]

Manipulate[Show[pressure[q, gamma], PlotRange -> {{0, rmax}, {0, q}}],
    {{q, 0.5, Style["Central pressure", Italic, 10]}, 0, 1, 0.01},
    {{gamma, 4/3, Style["gamma", Italic, 10]}, 1.01, 5/3 - 0.01, 0.01}
]
```

Changing `r^2` to `(r + 0.001)^2` solves the issue but it's an hack.  Now, I don't understand what's going on here!

Comment: Sorry, `rho[p_, gamma_] := 
 p^(1/gamma) + 
  p/(gamma - 1); Limit[-(m + 4 Pi p r^3) (rho[p, gamma] + 
     p)/((r) (r - 2 m)), r -> 0]` produces `Indeterminate`.

Comment: @user64494, at $r = 0$, we have $m(0) = 0$, $p(0) = q < \infty$ so $\rho(0) = \text{finite value}$.  Then `(rho + p)`is finite, and the factor `(m + 4 Pi p r^3)`
 goes to 0 faster than the denumerator `r (r - 2 m)`
.

Comment: I usually do it with `Piecewise`: `p'[r] == Piecewise[{{TOV[p[r], m[r], r, gamma], r != 0}}, 0]`, once I've found the value at the singularity.

Comment: @MichaelE2, thanks.  This is what I was about to do, but I'm wondering if there's a "better" way with Mathematica, when using NDSolve (maybe with a condition, in the WhenEvent?)

Comment: @MichaelE2, is there a way to replace the `rmax = 1` with a function of `q` and `gamma`
, such that if gives the value where `p = 0`?  Should I ask a new question about this?

Comment: It's the best way I've come up with over, say, the last ten years. It seems the most *mathematically* appropriate way (if you were taught the notion of "removable discontinuity" in calculus, for instance; like how to make $(e^x-1)/x$ continuous at $x=0$). And `NDSolve[]` handles `Piecewise[]` quite well usually. -- You can integrate `{r, 0, Infinity}` instead of `{r, 0, rmax}`. `NDSolve[]` will stop at the `WhenEvent[]` or `MaxSteps`, whichever happens first.

Comment: @MichaelE2, well this is what I did at first, using `rmax = 10`, say (try it in the code above).  But then I'm getting lots of errors when playing with the sliders.

Comment: It looks like `p` decays quickly. When the pressure goes negative, it is raised to the `1/gamma` **before** the `WhenEvent`. Maybe change `rho[p_, gamma_] := Abs[p]^(1/gamma) + p/(gamma - 1)`, since `p` is supposed to be positive.

Comment: @MichaelE2, there seems to be a few more quirks with this code.  How can I find the value of `r`such that `p`is very close to 0.001 (say `Rmax`), and use that value to find the value of `m[Rmax]`?  The integration takes a very large number of small steps when approaching `p = 0` and it doesn't seem to converge.

Comment: `WhenEvent[p[r] < 0.001, foo = m[r]; Rmax = r]`? -- It's when `q = 0` that there is trouble. Not sure why.  Some of it is underflow.

Comment: `WhenEvent[r > 1 && p[r] == 0, "StopIntegration"]` seems to fix `q = 0`. Use `r > 10` or whatever as desired.

Comment: @MichaelE2, sorry, I don't understand your last two modifications.  I need the graphics to be plotted from `r = 0`up to the value `Rmax`which gives `p = 0.001` (or 0?).  The graphics shouldn't allow to display much useless white space.  I also need the value of `m[r]`at this `Rmax` (for which pressure is almost 0), as a function of `q`and `gamma`.

Comment: @MichaelE2, maybe I should ask a new question about my last query, since you solved the one in the original question...

Comment: @MichaelE2, the trick of the PieceWise function doesn't work with the classical (non-relativist) version.  I'll edit my question, since my first issue isn't solved.  Now, I really don't understand what's going on!  :-(

Comment: About the classical version, I found that using `Method -> {ExplicitRungeKutta, "DiscontinuityProcessing" -> None}`instead of `"StiffnessSwitching"`solves some of my issues at `r = 0`
.

Answer (score 2):

Here's summary in code of the better suggestions I made or improvements/alternatives to them:

```
rmax = 1;

rho // ClearAll;
rho[p_?NumericQ, gamma_] := (* clip when p<0 *)
  If[p < 0, 0., p^(1/gamma) + p/(gamma - 1)];
TOV // ClearAll;
TOV[p_, m_, r_, 
   gamma_] := -(m + 4 Pi p r^3) (rho[p, gamma] + 
      p)/((r(*+0.01*)) (r - 2 m));

solution // ClearAll;
solution[q_, gamma_] := (solution["Data"] = {}; (* for saving data
                     since getting data out was raised in comments *)
   With[{
     ndsol = NDSolve[{
        p'[r] == 
         Piecewise[{{TOV[p[r], m[r], r, gamma], r != 0}}, 0],(*Equ.1*)
        m'[r] == 4 Pi rho[p[r], gamma] r^2,(*Equ.2*)
        p[0] == q,(*Central pressure*)
        m[0] == 0,(*Mass at center*)
        WhenEvent[p[r] < 0.001,  (* from a comment *)
         solution["Data"] = {"stop" -> "p < 0.001", "m@Rmax" -> m[r], 
           "Rmax" -> r};
         "StopIntegration"],
        WhenEvent[ (* event shouldn't happen b/c of prev. event *)
         (Developer`MachineComplexQ[p[r]] || p[r] < 0 || 2 m[r] >= r),
         solution["Data"] = {"stop" -> "p negative-ish"};
         "StopIntegration",
         "LocationMethod" -> "StepEnd"],
        WhenEvent[r > 1 && p[r] == 0, (* stop infinite integration case *)
         solution["Data"] = {"stop" -> "p = 0", 
           "m@Rmax" -> Indeterminate, "Rmax" -> Indeterminate};
         "StopIntegration"]
        }, {p, m}, {r, 0, rmax; Infinity},
       Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", MaxSteps -> Automatic]
     },
    If[("stop" /. solution["Data"]) === "p negative-ish",
     solution["Data"] = Join[
       solution["Data"],
       {"m@Rmax" -> Last[m@"ValuesOnGrid" /. First@ndsol], 
        "Rmax" -> First@Last[m@"Grid" /. First@ndsol]}]
     ];
    solution["Data"] = 
     Association@AppendTo[solution["Data"], "solution" -> ndsol]];
   solution["Data"]["solution"]
   );
pressure[q_, gamma_] := With[{ndsol = solution[q, gamma]},
   Plot[
    Evaluate[p[r] /. ndsol],
    Evaluate@Flatten@{r, p@"Domain" /. ndsol},
    PlotRange -> All,
    PlotLabel -> Row[{
       solution["Data"]["stop"], ", ",
       Subscript[r, "max"], "=", solution["Data"]["Rmax"], ", ",
       m@Subscript[r, "max"], "=", solution["Data"]["m@Rmax"]
       }],
    ImageSize -> 400]
   ];

Manipulate[
 pressure[q, gamma],
 {{q, 0.5, Style["Central pressure", Italic, 10]}, 0, 1, 0.01},
 {{gamma, 4/3, Style["gamma", Italic, 10]}, 1.01, 5/3 - 0.01, 0.01},
 TrackedSymbols :> Manipulate]
```

[image]

```
solution["Data"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Wow!  There are lots of things in there that I don't understand.  I'll have to study that solution...

Comment: Apparently, the Max values of `r`and `m`can be found with `Rmax[q_, gamma_] := (p/.solution[q, gamma])[[1]][[1]][[1]][[2]]`and `Mmax[q_, gamma_] := m[Rmax[q, gamma]]/.solution[q, gamma][[1]]`, is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.  So will `(p["Domain"] /. First@solution[q, gamma])[[1, 2]]` and
`Last[m["ValuesOnGrid"] /. First@solution[q, gamma]]` respectively.

Comment: Micheal, when I modify slightly the code, I'm frequently getting error messages about complex numbers.  What complex numbers have anything to do with this NDSolve code?  How can I prevent these numbers (with $i$) to get into the calculations?

Comment: @Cham `real^noninteger` yields complex when the base is negative. There are other functions such that `f[real]` can be complex, like `Log[negative]` and inverse trig. But the only place I saw it in your original code was in `rho[]` with `p^(1/gamma)`. Once the complex numbers creep in, they propagate. Here 0^3 with round-off error yields complex: `(-$MachineEpsilon)^(3 + 3 $MachineEpsilon)`. For `p^(1/gamma)`, I suggested `Abs[p]^(1/gamma)` originally, also tried `Re[p]^(1/gamma)`, and settled for `If[..]` above. A somewhat higher `AccuracyGoal` sometimes can help keep `p` from going negative.

Comment: Ah, yes, it makes sense.  But then I need to enforce the positivity of all quantities.  I'm not sure it may change the physics, though, by adding things like `Abs[]`everywhere, especially to find $r_{max}$ around $p = 0$ (without an arbitrary cutoff).

Comment: I'm now thinking that the max value $r_{max}$ should be found with the condition `m'[r] = 0`instead of `p[r] < 0.0001` (arbitrary cutoff).  What do you think?

Comment: Hmm, the last suggestion doesn't seem to work, or I don't know how to implement it as a condition in `WhenEvent[]`.

Comment: @Cham *What do you think?* -- I assume that's an (astro)physics question. Kinda out of my area. Doesn't `m'[r] == 0` when `rho[p, gamma] == 0`, that is, at `p[r] -> (1 - gamma)^(gamma/(-1 + gamma))`? -- For `WhenEvent[]`, you cannot use the top derivatives as "state variables", that is, `WhenEvent[m'[r] == 0,...]` does not work. Not sure why that's a restriction.

Comment: Your last formula doesn't apply because pressure and density should stay positive (or 0) in all cases.  So when `rho = 0`, then `p = 0` too (`rho` is defined as the sum of two positive quantities).  I tried the stopping condition `rho[p[r], gamma] < 0.001`and it works as for the pressure, but then the cutoff value is still arbitrary.  I don't know what to think of the cutoff.

Comment: @Cham `rho[p, gamma] == 0` is derived from `m'[r] == 0` using the formula for `m'[r]` in the ODEs (`m'[r]` is a positive scalar times `rho[..]`. So it can't be zero unless `rho[] == 0`. Despite the physics implications.)

Comment: Yes, I agree with all of this, but since `p >= 0`and `rho >= 0`, there's only one mathematical solution to the equation `rho = 0`:  $p = 0$.

Comment: @Cham My point was that [your suggestion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/288315/how-to-remove-an-apparent-singularity-in-ndsolve/288320?noredirect=1#comment717912_288320) to find `rMax` from `m'[r] == 0` leads to this condition.